# Open tab programmatically with bootstrap-native without jquery

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, tabs, bootstrap-native

I'm using the non JQuery library bootstrap-native for Bootstrap 4 [Link](https://thednp.github.io/bootstrap.native/v4.html) and I need to open a tab programmatically.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

When with jquery I would do:

```
$('#contact').tab('show')
```

`.tab('show')` doesn't work, is there a way to do this with plain javascript?

Answer (score -1):

```
<! --You Forgot creating container div -->    
<div id="TabMain" class="container"> 
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-    tab">Contacts</div>
    </div>
</div>
```